# How to display username in a String contained in an array

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-edittext

I can't figure out how to display the username from the previous activity in the second activity.

I have tried a bunch of method but none of them get me to display the Username in the String

This is the MainActivity :

```
       private EditText nameField;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nameField = findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
    Button startButton = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = nameField.getText().toString();
            getusername(name);
        }
    });

}

private void getusername(String name) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OneShot.class);
    Resources resources = getResources();
    String key = resources.getString(R.string.key_name);
    intent.putExtra(key, name);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is the SecondActivity :

```
 public static final String TAG = OneShot.class.getSimpleName();
private String name;
private int nextSentenceId = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one_shot);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    name = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.key_name));
    if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
        name = "Player";
    }
    Log.d(TAG, name);

    final int[] sentences = new int[]{R.string.page0, R.string.page2, R.string.page3, R.string.page4, R.string.page5 };

    Button next= findViewById(R.id.next);
    final TextView displayText= findViewById(R.id.displayText);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int limit = 5;
            if(nextSentenceId < sentences.length){
                displayText.setText(sentences[nextSentenceId]);
                ++nextSentenceId;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Those are the Strings in the int[] :

```
     <string name="page0"> Hello %1$s </string>
<string name="page2"> Welcome into this application </string>
<string name="page3"> How are you ? </string>
<string name="page4"> How is the weather </string>
<string name="page5"> Is %1$s you\'re real name ? </string>
```

Why isn't the username passed in the string sentences and how can I fix it ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

1. strings in your array to lead them to correct format:

   ```
   <string name="page0">Hello %s</string>
   <string name="page5">Is %s your real name?</string>
   ```
2. call to set the text in the TextView in accordance with the format above:

   ```
   displayText.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), getString(sencences[nextSentenceId]), name));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the `int` array is not the `String` values, but rather the ids that are used to link to said `String` resource. You can get the `String` resource(value) associated with the id using `getResources().getString(R.string.yourstring)`.

```
//So, instead of 
//displayText.setText(sentences[nextSentenceId]);

//use
displayText.setText(getResources().getString(sentences[nextSentenceId]));
```